# jquery cycle plugin don't cycle on next

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, jquery-cycle

I'm using the cycle plugin for an image slider with two links (next and prev) to cycle through them and so far it works just fine, I was wondering it it was possible to make it so when you hit the last image it doesn't cycle back to the first image, in this case I just want it to do nothing, I've been looking at the options but I can't find if there's any that let's you toggle this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using cycle lite or the full cycle plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration option called `nowrap`. All you need to do is set `nowrap: true` in your configuration options.

[Cycle Options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

Comment: Thanks! I must have been blind :(

Comment: I missed it at first too...I actually tried a couple of different things before I found it, lol.